# How to convert declarations placed on a single line to multi-liners using regex?

Tags: regex

I have the following C code text in an auto-generated file:

```
typedef struct {
     double re, im;
} creal_T;
```

that I want to transform into:

```
typedef struct {
     double re; 
     double im;
} creal_T;
```

using regex.

How can this be done? I want to search for any declarations of the type `double re, im` and move them to separate lines.

Comment: To clarify:
1) Will there only ever be two arguments to split, 5, or any number?
2) Is "typedef struct { ... } creal_T;" something static?
3) What language do you prefer to use to do the replacements?

Comment: My current need is only ever two arguments. But out of curiosity a more general solution would also be of interest. Added clarifications of this into the question.

Comment: 1) Yes
2) Yes, it is a static c struct generated from Matlab that I want to re-arrange.
3) I am working on this c file with a matlab script, so a replace solution like this one (removing comments) would be great: regexprep(fileContent, '\/\*[\s\S]*?\*\/|([^:]|^)\/\/.*$', '');

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
^(\W*)double\s*(re|im|x|y|z)\W*(re|im|x|y|z)
```

You would wrap it in something like this for python:

```
# coding=utf8
# the above tag defines encoding for this document and is for Python 2.x compatibility

import re

regex = r"^(\W*)double\s*(re|im|x|y|z)\W*(re|im|x|y|z)"

test_str = ("typedef struct {\n"
    "     double re, im;\n"
    "} creal_T;\n\n"
    "typedef struct {\n"
    "     double x, y;\n"
    "} creal_T;\n\n"
    "typedef struct {\n"
    "     double z;\n"
    "} creal_T;")

subst = "\\g<1>double \\g<2>;\\r\\g<1>double \\g<3>"

# You can manually specify the number of replacements by changing the 4th argument
result = re.sub(regex, subst, test_str, 0, re.MULTILINE)

if result:
    print (result)

# Note: for Python 2.7 compatibility, use ur"" to prefix the regex and u"" to prefix the test string and substitution.
```

This code was generated by https://regex101.com/

Comment: Thank you! This worked just fine :) 
For others using Matlab, the syntax becomes:
`result = regexprep(codeText, '(?m)^(\W*)double\s*(re|im)\W*(re|im)', '$1double $2;\n$1double $3');`